# Using multiple AVPlayer in a tableview like instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

I'm trying to implement an AVPlayer into each row of a tableview cell but I don't find any good documentation. I would like to have a timeline like Instagram but I have no idea how to handle multiple players and tapgestures inside..  Any idea where I can find some?

Comment: Show what you have tried (the code) and explain what it does wrong. Have you considered alternative approaches? Do the cells really need to contain players, or can they be images with tap detection to open a player...

Comment: I tried a tons of different tutorials but i didn't find how to handle it into a tableview. 
The cells need to contains player.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend not having all of the cells contain players. There really isn't a reason to as you aren't going to be playing all of the cells on screen at the same time (indeed I hope that isn't the plan).

Instead, I would have each of the cells contain only an image, preferably of the first frame or somewhere in the first few seconds of each video. Preferably you have these already but it is possible to grab these images from the videos (separate research topic...).

Then, you could simply wait for the user to tap the cell (or a play button over the image) and then transition the contents of the cell to a player instead of the image (and stop any other cell from playing). This should look and work basically identically to players in all cells but requires less resource loading and allows better image caching.

Comment: that sounds a good idea but I don't know how to do that. 
The problem is that i would like to do what does the instagram app, preload movie and play it as soon as the user see it, is that possible with that method?

Comment: You could create a player when a cell is on screen for a certain amount of time (start a timer when the delegate is told the cell is displayed, check it's still displayed when it fires, kill any other player). I'd get the basics of image display and user interaction working first and then look at automatic playback and preventing multiple-playback issues...