# play multiple videos smoothly in CollectionView like Facebook

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement an AVPlayer into each row of a Collection cell but I don't find any good documentation.Any idea where I can find some?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263884/using-multiple-avplayer-in-a-tableview-like-instagram?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"something" ofType:@"mp4"]]];
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
[self.moviePlayer play];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

- self.movieplayer is an instance of MPMoviePlayerController (not MPMoviePlayerViewController). In my experience it's important to declare it as a property (like so: @property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;) rather than a simple ivar, because sometimes it just doesn't work if it's an ivar
- setting the frame is also important, because if we don't set it, the video will not appear at all. The frame can be anything as long as what you define is within the bounds of your view
- Important: As above, when defining the URL use NSURL's URLWithString method if you want to access the file through a network and use NSURL's fileUrlWithPath if you have the file locally!