# How to use avaudioplayer in a table view cell? Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a table view that handles audio files. I am able to play the audio files from each cell but not the way it actually should be. I want it as when one audio is being played in a cell then if i click on another cell's play button, the other audio should pause and proceed with the audio of the cell i have clicked last. And also if i scroll the cells out of the table view the player is being reset when i scroll back to that cell. I dont want the player reset. How do i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creates only one player, not one for every cell, and when someone wants to play content from a specific cell just play the audio file on the unique player you have.

Comment: have you tried to use AVQueuePlayer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer . I am not sure if it fulfills your purpose.
Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263884/using-multiple-avplayer-in-a-tableview-like-instagram